# Use of "the" in the given sentence

Tags: definite-article

Should "the" be written before the word "invoice" in the following sentence?

> "I have attached the translation and **invoice**."

Comment: I think we need a larger excerpt.

Comment: Was there one attachment (a "translation and invoice") or two (a translation and an invoice)?

Comment: Here is the context. I have completed a translation and sending the file to my client. I also attach an invoice.

Comment: Both "the (translation and invoice)" and "the (translation) and the (invoice)" are acceptable. Normally one would use your example, unless there was a reason to emphasize *the invoice.*

Comment: There are two files. One is translation and the other is invoice.

Comment: I suppose you mean the invoice of the translation, not the translation of the invoice.

Comment: Yes, I mean the invoice of the translation.

Comment: Then l'd say the translation and its invoice.